# Moving heart using a constructor function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a heart move left and right, using a constructor function. This is what I've got so far, for display

```
for(var a = 0; a < TWO_PI; a+=0.01){
     this.r = this.x, 5;
     this.b = this.r* 16 pow(sin(a), 3);
     this.c = -this.r*(13* cos(a) - 5 * cos(2*a) -2*cos(3*a) - cos(4*a));

     vertex(this.b, this.c);
}
```

all the var have been defined, but the image is only moving one line and add `this.x` to every line make the image not show, although the console is not saying anything. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please include a bit more code:  
Is the `for` loop inside `vertex` object?  
Doesn't this `this.x, 5` give you an error?!?  
Is `TWO_PI` given value somewhere?  
Don't `pow`, `sin`, and `cos` need `Math.` in front of them?  
Move `vertex(this.b, this.c);` into the code quote...

Comment: This code misses an operator in `this.r* 16 pow(sin(a), 3);` between `16` and `pow`